# Remove default right margin of a div

Tags: html, css

I need to remove default right margin of a div:
[image]

this is my simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css:

```
#mydiv
    {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    background-color: green;    
    }
```

But margin-right property doesn't work.

is there some way to remove the margin?

Comment: Check `!important` and `css resets`

Comment: Check http://cssreset.com/

Comment: seems to be body margin, try to set body{margin:0}

Comment: You can as well remove `margin-left`

Comment: just remove `width:100%;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ngxr4qt/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/5ngxr4qt/1/  @SheraliTurdiyev

Answer (score 4):

you can try this one:

```
#mydiv
    {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;

    background-color: green;    
    }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/21yurnqu/)

Remove `margin-top:-8px;margin-left: -8px;margin-right: -8px;` and add `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

The `body` element has a non-zero margin by default.

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

please find updated code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpm5Lhew/)

Also please note that before applying any CSS to the page try to apply reset css, to reset element default styles for example -

`

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This should do the trick...

Hover over the `<div>` in the snippet to see.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
  float: right;
}
div:hover {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```